# Plugin that provides the [edit] shortcode?

Tags: plugins, shortcode

Several months ago, I was browsing around the Internet and came across a WordPress site that had updates on the posts enclosed in `[edit]...[/edit]`. Obviously this was a function provided by a plugin that was no longer active.

I searched Google and the WordPress plugin directory for a plugin that provided this shortcode, but found nothing. Presumably the content within `[edit]...[/edit]` (or `[edit date="yyyy-mm-dd"]...[/edit]`) was displayed in a special way, like a revision list below the post or something.

Are there any plugins that do this? I immediately wanted to add the functionality a plugin that would use a shortcode set up in that way to my site, but couldn't find the plugin.

Comment: Hmm isn't this for what the ins and del buttons are for? I'm a bit puzzeled about the benefit of a shortcode here.

Answer (score 1):

A [Google code search for `"add_shortcode('edit'"`](http://www.google.com/codesearch?hl=en&lr=&q=%22add_shortcode%28%27edit%27%22&sbtn=Search) gives me only one hit: [Shailan Theme Framework](http://shailan.com/wordpress/themes/framework/), with [an `edit` shortcode](http://code.google.com/p/widgetbox-theme/source/browse/trunk/framework/shailan-shortcodes.php?spec=svn109&r=109#547) that places the edit link in your content. Probably not what you want?

Comment: No, but that search is a good one. I don't think Google knows about the plugin I'm looking for, though. It's probably long discontinued/dead.

Answer (score 1):

Creating your own within the functions file would be rather straightforward. Take a look at this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: Answers should be more than links :)